# A possible redundant step in Evans's proof of the Lax-Milgram theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to understand the proof of the following theorem in Evans's PDE book.

> [image]
>   [image]

**The first step is to rewrite the bilinear form using the Riesz representation theorem**:
[image]

**Then the properties of the operator $A$ are proved:**
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Eventually the Riesz reprensentation theorem is used again to give the existence:**
[image]

**The very last step gives the uniqueness:**
[image]

> Could anyone identify where the one-to-one property of $A$ is used? I suspect that that is redundant in the proof.

Comment: The property could have been used to prove uniqueness of the vector, but it appears the argument was repeated to show uniqueness directly, at a later point.

Comment: @TrialAndError: This is what [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1487058/9464) asked and I [think](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2069823/9464) step 5 only gives the existence not the uniqueness. (If one applies the one-to-one property of $A$ in step 5 though, one should get the uniqueness only for those solutions obtained *via* the Riesz representation of $f$.)

Comment: The 1-1 property of A could be used to establish uniqueness. But, as I wrote in the first comment, it appears they repeated the argument, one for uniqueness, and once for 1-1.

Comment: Au=f. Because $A$ is 1-1, then $u$ is unique.

Comment: I don't see how you can conclude that $Au=f$.

Comment: I'm assuming $H$ is a Hilbert space. $f$ is identified with a vector.

Comment: @TrialAndError: Fair enough. $B[u,v]=\langle f,v\rangle$ if and only if $(Au,v)=(w,v)$. Now the 1-1 property of $A$ implies that such $u$ must be unique. I agree with you now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed redundant as @TrialAndError pointed out in the comment. The 1-1 property of $A$ can be used in Step 5 to show the uniqueness given by Step 6. In the whole proof, one can either drop the 1-1 property of $A$ or Step 6. Evans might just think it is clearer for students to put in the extra step.